# Copy values from multiple keys from array of object

Tags: javascript

I want to copy value of name and age into another array, below code is working fine, But I wanted to know better way to do it.

```
const users = [
    { id: 0, name: 'John', age:34 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Wayne', age:44 },
    { id: 2, name: 'David', age:24 },
];
let values=[];
 users && users.map(user => {
            values.push(user['name'])
            values.push(user['age'])

        })
        console.log(values);
```

output

```
['John', 34, 'Wayne', 44, 'David', 24]
```

Comment: _"better"_ how?

Comment: with less code, in some standard way, instead of pushing, can we return

Comment: `const values = (users) ? users.map(el => [el.name, el.age]).flat() : [];` One line code, next time if you want a review of code use [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: another alternative. simple and readable: `const values = [];

users.forEach(user => {
    values.push(user.name)
    values.push(user.age)
})`

Comment: If your goal is to get less code, then use a minifier. Though I'd personally strive for readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind each items to an array containing both its name and age and then flattern these arrays.

This can be done using [Array#FlatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const users = [
    { id: 0, name: 'John', age:34 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Wayne', age:44 },
    { id: 2, name: 'David', age:24 },
];

const nameAndAges = users.flatMap(user => [user.name, user.age])

console.log(nameAndAges)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good, this can be also solved in different ways, I guess you may want to create function for handling this.

```js
const users = [
    { id: 0, name: 'John', age: 34 },
    { id: 1, name: 'Wayne', age: 44 },
    { id: 2, name: 'David', age: 24 },
];

const result = mapArrayToProps(users, ['name', 'age']);

function mapArrayToProps(arr, props) {
    return arr.flatMap(obj => mapObjectToProps(obj, props));
}

function mapObjectToProps(obj, props) {
    return props.map(prop => obj[prop])
}

console.log(result);
```